# dplyr: calculate the percentage of levels in many columns in data.frame and convert it to wide

Tags: r, dplyr

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("site1", 3), rep("site2", 8), rep("site3", 9), rep("site4", 15)),
                 major_rock = c("greywacke",    "mudstone", "gravel",   "greywacke",    "gravel",   "mudstone", "gravel", "mudstone", "mudstone",   
                                "conglomerate", "gravel", "mudstone",   "greywacke","conglomerate", "gravel",   "gravel",   "greywacke","gravel",   
                                "greywacke",    "gravel",   "mudstone", "greywacke",    "gravel", "gravel", "gravel",   "conglomerate", "greywacke",
                                "coquina",  "gravel",   "gravel",   "greywacke",    "gravel",   "mudstone","mudstone",  "gravel"),
                 minor_rock = c("sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",  "limestone",   "sand silt clay", "sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",
                                "sand silt clay", "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", NA, "limestone",  "mudstone sandstone coquina limestone",
                                "sandstone mudstone limestone",  "sand loess silt",  "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", "sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",
                                "sandstone mudstone limestone", "sand loess silt", "loess silt sand", "sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt",
                                "sand silt clay",  "sandstone mudstone conglomerate", "loess sand silt", "sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra", "sandstone mudstone basalt chert limestone",
                                "sand loess silt", "sand silt clay", "loess silt sand",  "sandstone mudstone limestone", "sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt",
                                "limestone", "loess sand silt",  NA, "sandstone mudstone conglomerate", "sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite", "limestone",
                                "mudstone sandstone coquina limestone", "mudstone tephra loess"),
                 area_ha = c(1066.68,   7.59,   3.41,   4434.76,    393.16, 361.69, 306.75, 124.93, 95.84,  9.3,    8.45,   4565.89,    2600.44,    2198.52,    
                             2131.71,   2050.09,    1640.47,    657.09, 296.73, 178.12, 10403.53,   8389.2,  8304.08,   3853.36,    2476.36,    2451.25,    
                             1640.47,   1023.02,    532.94, 385.68, 296.73, 132.45, 124.93, 109.12, 4.87))
```

**What I want?**

I need to prepare `df` for another analysis that requires each site to have one row only. So in the final data.frame `df_fin`, each site will have the proportion of the levels in `major_rock`and `minor_rock` and the column names (variables) will be the levels of `major_rock`and `minor_rock`.

I can do this for each variable (`major_rock` and `minor_rock`) and then combine them like below

**What I did?**

For major_rock

```
library(tidyverse)

df_major_rock <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-minor_rock) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id, major_rock) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(total_area = sum(area_ha)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(percent_major = total_area/sum(total_area) * 100) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-total_area) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(major_rock, percent_major)

> df_major_rock
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: id [4]

      id conglomerate  coquina     gravel greywacke   mudstone
* <fctr>        <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1  site1           NA       NA  0.3164205  98.97929  0.7042907
2  site2    0.1621656       NA 12.3517842  77.32960 10.1564462
3  site3   13.4720995       NA 30.7432536  27.80577 27.9788787
4  site4    6.1085791 2.549393 39.0992422  25.73366 26.5091274
```

The same for minor_rock

```
df_minor_rock <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-major_rock) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id, minor_rock) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(total_area = sum(area_ha)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(percent_minor = total_area/sum(total_area) * 100)%>% 
  dplyr::select(-total_area) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(minor_rock, percent_minor)

> df_minor_rock
Source: local data frame [4 x 15]
Groups: id [4]

      id limestone `loess sand silt` `loess silt sand` `mudstone sandstone coquina limestone` `mudstone tephra loess` `sand loess silt`
* <fctr>     <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>                                  <dbl>                   <dbl>             <dbl>
1  site1 0.7042907                NA                NA                                     NA                      NA                NA
2  site2 2.1784240                NA                NA                              1.6711771                      NA          0.147344
3  site3        NA          1.091484         12.562550                                     NA                      NA         13.062701
4  site4 2.8607214          1.328100          6.171154                              0.2719299              0.01213617         20.693984
# ... with 8 more variables: `sand silt clay` <dbl>, `sandstone conglomerate coquina tephra` <dbl>, `sandstone mudstone basalt chert
#   limestone` <dbl>, `sandstone mudstone conglomerate` <dbl>, `sandstone mudstone conglomerate chert limestone basalt` <dbl>, `sandstone
#   mudstone limestone` <dbl>, `sandstone siltstone mudstone limestone silt lignite` <dbl>, `<NA>` <dbl>
```

Then, I joined the two data.frames together (`df_major_rock` and `df_minor_rock`) so the final the data.frame df_fin will have 4 observations only (one row for each site) and the variables will be the levels of `major_rock` and `minor_rock`

```
df_fin <- df_major_rock %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(., df_minor_rock, by="id")
```

**Question**

`df_fin` is exactly what I want. However, in this reproducible example, I showed only 2 variables (major_rock and minor_rock) that I had to create two different data.frames to get the proportions of the levels of each variable and then join them together to get the final output `df_fin`. In my actual data, I have many variables other than `major_rock` and `minor_rock` that I want to get the proportions of their levels for each site as well. I think there should be straightforward or shorter approach than mine. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten this a bit by using `data.table::dcast` which will spread out your data into columns.  You can then use rowSums to calculate the percentage in one step.  While there may be a better way to do this I wrapped this approach for each column in a loop:

```
df_fin  <- data.frame(id = unique(df$id))
myColumns <- setdiff(colnames(df)[-1], "area_ha")

for (name in myColumns){
  dcastFormula <- paste0("id ~ ", name)
  tempdf <- data.table::dcast(df, dcastFormula, sum)
  tempdf[,-1] <-  tempdf[,-1]/rowSums(tempdf[,-1],na.rm = TRUE)*100
  df_fin  <- left_join(df_fin , tempdf, by ="id")
}
```

As always there are probably several other ways to do this, but this is one example that is a bit simpler than the your starting place.  Also it could need to be modified depending on your other columns and/or how you wish to aggregate them.

Comment: I think in the last line in the function, MyExample should be tempdf.